# How do parquet data types map to hive data types?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Parquet has many data types as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/sdk/parquet-to-cdm-datatype

how do they all map to hive's data types?

Comment: what exactly is the issue here? hive can access a parquet table, so there is no need to convert.

Comment: The issue is that I need to know how parquet data types map to hive data types in order to be able to create a hive table over parquet data.

Comment: I would say, why you need to create a `hive` table? From hive can you not access that parquet table directly? also, what is your hive formatted table?

Comment: No, I have to create that table over parquet files, I can't access it directly.

Comment: ok so create one sample table and see if your data is correct or not.

Comment: @KoushikRoy that is annoying, there has to be a reference, that shows mapping from parquet types to hive types.